# Es posible utilizar Tkinter de forma online?

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo una duda, si se puede utilizar Tkinter en una web, es decir, subir mi tkinter a una pagina web.

Comment: No parece posible.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter no es más que un *wrapper* de python para tcl/tk. Existe un modo para ver un interface tcl/tk en un navegador moderno usado como servidor VNC: [CloudTK](http://cloudtk.tcl-lang.org/).

En los ejemplos disponibles tienes uno para tkinter: [ejemplos cloudtk](http://cloudtk.tcl-lang.org:5443/cloudtk/) (casi al final).

En mi opinión, demasiado esfuerzo para conseguir que siga funcionando una aplicación tkinter. Si la aplicación no es complicada, es más recomendable rehacer el interface web completo en django o flask.